# What is the difference between find and findOne in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

find returns one item.

And, findOne, also returns one item.

but if I look in documentation, find doesn't exist.

yet it I have projects where I've been using just find.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use them interchangeably. When I tried breaking it by giving it an id instead of an object I got an error reffering to the method as `.findOne`. Perhaps it is a left over from a pervious version of Sequelize (I couldn't find any good old docs so this is just a guess) ?

Anyway, you should probably use the more descriptive `.findOne` over `.find` or pick one and be consistant.

Answer (score 3):

findOne is the preferred method and find is removed in Sequelize v5.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md